# Compute the matrix given by the infinite sum

Tags: linear-algebra

We let the matrix $$J = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_{1} & 1 & 0\\
0 & \lambda_{1} & 1\\
0 & 0 & \lambda_{1}\end{pmatrix}$$. I need to find the matrix given by the infinite sum $I + xJ + \frac{1}{2!}x^2J^2 + \frac{1}{3!} x^3J^3 + \cdots + \frac{1}{n!}x^nJ^{n} + \cdots$. I've shown that $J^n = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_{1}^{n} & n\lambda_{1}^{n-1} & \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \lambda_{1}^{n-2} \\
0 & \lambda_{1}^{n} & n\lambda_{1}^{n-1}\\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_{1}^{n}\\ \end{pmatrix}$. We essentially want to know $exp(xJ)$, which I'm confused about how to compute. Could anyone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: What is $x$ in your question?

Comment: @ShyamalSayak I've edited my post. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: So you don't really want $\exp(J)$, you want $\exp(xJ)$.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak Yes, I believe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did most of the work already.  You have
$$
J^n = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_{1}^{n} & n\lambda_{1}^{n-1} & \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \lambda_{1}^{n-2} \\
0 & \lambda_{1}^{n} & n\lambda_{1}^{n-1}\\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_{1}^{n}\\ \end{pmatrix} .
$$
So, the upper-left entry of $\exp(J)$ is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\;\lambda_{1}^{n} = e^{\lambda_1} .
$$
The next entry to the right is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\;n\lambda_1^{n-1} = e^{\lambda_1} .
$$
The upper-right entry is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\;\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\;\lambda_1^{n-2} = \frac{1}{2}\;e^{\lambda_1} .
$$
And so on.

Comment: Now that the question changed to $\exp(xJ)$, I will let you use the same method for that.

Answer (score 3):

One can write $J$ as $A+B$, with $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \lambda_1 & 0\\
0&0&\lambda_1
\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then $\exp(J)=\exp(A)\exp(B)$. The rest should be easy as $A$ is a diagonal matrix, and $B$ is nilpotent.

Comment: $Ax$ and $Bx$   also commute;  it was presented in an odd way, but the $x$  may be correct.

Comment: anyway, it is what you need for ODE system $y' = Jy$